# expected expression error trying to store data with NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, parse-error

I'm trying to use `NSUserDefaults` to store whether a switch is on or off in this code:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:switch.on forKey:@"switchState"];
```

But I'm getting the error `expected expression` on the `setBool:switch.on` bit (the error marker is at the beginning of switch). How do I fix this?

Also it's inside an `IBAction` if that helps:

```
- (IBAction)mathTaskSwitched:(id)sender
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:switch.on forKey:@"switchState"];
}
```

I haven't got any more code to do with this except for where I try and access it but I don't think that has anything to do with the error.

Thanks

Comment: `switch` is a keyword. Name your variable something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because `switch` is an reserved keyword. You are using that as a variable name.

Change your variable name, that will fix the issue.

If it is an instance variable, you can use it like `self.switch.on`. But better approach will be not using any reserved keyword for your variables/constants.